# Does the C++11 memory model allow hoisting relaxed atomic loads out of loops?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

Consider the following code:

```
#include <atomic>

extern std::atomic<int> i;

void f(void)
{
  while (!i.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
      ;
}
```

I'm looking for a citation from the C++11 standard that says that the compiler is not allowed to transform the loop into

```
  if (!i.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
    while (1)
      ;
  }
```

I've seen some discussion [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/509596/) but nothing conclusive.

**Edit**: A previous version of this post called an extern function inside the loop.

**Edit 2**: For motivation: The book "Effective Java" says that the HotSpot VM performs the following transformation:

```
while (!done)
    i++;
```

to

```
if (!done)
    while (true)
        i++;
```

even though it's perfectly defined behavior for another thread to change the **done** variable concurrently.

Comment: Please choose a language. The answer is different in C and C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB C11 and C++11 have the same memory model.

Comment: @2501 No they don't. I guess you mean to say they have the same rules for atomic memory ordering.

Comment: This isn't valid C++, in any event. There's no `_Atomic` or `stdatomic.h` in C++.

Comment: The question previously contained the C tag but someone removed it. You can easily transform it into the equivalent C++ version but I hope the answer is the same in both languages.

Comment: @MuhKarma: Someone from the C world told me once that C has a special rule that allows `while (1)`. I've not followed that up, but it's the kind of difference between the two languages that would be typical.

Comment: Some combination of the title, code, or tags, need to be changed for this question to make it valid in at least one language. Right now the title and tags are C++, but the code is C, and the content of the question mentions both.

Comment: Yeah, C11 allows a loop "whose controlling expression is a constant expression". So `for(;;);` is UB but `while(1);` is not.  A use case for the latter is an embedded system where the main thread starts up various  ISRs or event handlers and then just idles for the rest of the run, with the program logic occurring in triggered events

Comment: @M.M N1570, fn 156: "An omitted controlling expression is replaced by a nonzero constant, which is a constant expression."

Comment: @M.M for(;;) is not ub: *An omitted controlling expression is replaced by a nonzero constant, which is a constant expression.*

Comment: I stand corrected  (and am happy about it, it's a bit dumb to have those two bits of code behave differently)

Answer (score 2):

Forget about relaxed, there's no guarantee that an atomic store *ever* become visible to an atomic load in a different thread. The best you get is the normative encouragement in [[atomics.order]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/atomics#order-12) (and analogous wording in [[intro.progress]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.progress#18)):

> Implementations should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads
>   within a reasonable amount of time.

...which is not a requirement.

(C11 has identical wording in §7.11.3/16)

Since hoisting the load leads to behavior indistinguishable from a non-hoisted load where the store never becomes visible, and since the latter is conforming, an implementation is allowed by the as-if rule to hoist the load regardless of the memory order used.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that the original code may trigger undefined behaviour or what?

Comment: There's no UB, but there's no guarantee from the memory model that that loop will ever terminate regardless of the kind of load you do. Everything is QoI.

Comment: Not even with a volatile atomic variable?

Comment: @xvan That should prevent the compiler from hoisting out the load, but visibility of the store can still be delayed for as long as it pleases.

Comment: This doesn't *seem* to answer the question. I think we'd all agree that if the OP had used `memory_order_seq_cst` his spinlock would work fine (i.e., if one thread set `i` to `1`, then the next thread to awake would *have* to see that update). The OP's question is whether changing it to `memory_order_relaxed` breaks the spinlock (by permitting the compiler to hoist the load out of the loop), or whether it's still required to work and if so why. FWIW, my intuition matches the OP's — that it shouldn't work — but I've also confirmed via godbolt that GCC doesn't hoist in practice on ARM/MIPS/PPC.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Nope. There's no requirement that a `memory_order_seq_cst` write becomes visible to another thread within any finite amount of time.

Comment: @T.C. Are you saying that a spinlock with `memory_order_seq_cst` is broken because there's no requirement that a write becomes visible to another thread within any finite amount of time, or what exactly is your "Nope" responding to?

Comment: @jhoffman0x A non-hoisted load where the store never becomes visible and a "hoisted" load have identical behavior: the loop never terminates. Since the store need not become visible within any finite amount of time, under the as-if rule it is conforming for the implementation to hoist the load regardless of the memory order used for the load. Now, this would be a *very low quality* implementation, and nobody in their right mind would do it (if only because nobody will buy such a thing), but it is a conforming one.

Comment: OP asked for a citation from the standard; my point is that such a citation cannot exist because 1) a conforming implementation may never make the store visible and 2) a hoisted load is indistinguishable from 1).

Comment: "Under the as-if rule it is conforming for the implementation to hoist the load regardless of the memory order used for the load." So that would be a defect in the standard then right? Do you know where I could find more discussions about the issue?

Comment: @T.C.  Do you know why the standard allows the store to never become visible?  I understand that the standard cannot stipulate an exact number of nanoseconds for such a thing but is there no way to constrain it just a little?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Presumably to support some esoteric hardware architecture where it's not possible to guarantee that. I don't know an example offhand though.